# Click event not firing with Backbone & jQuery

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm using Backbone in an app & running into an situation where events are not firing.

My View, maps to a dialog interface containing several controls (a text area, a couple radio buttons, etc.) and a save button.  I'm defining the following events:

```
events: {
        'input': 'onchange',
        'change': 'onchange',
        'click .save': 'save',
        'click .cancel': 'cancel',
    },
```

1. Each time any form element in the dialog changes, I fire `onchange`, which performs some validation and either enables or disables the save button.
2. In the 'normal' flow, everything works properly.  I fill out the textarea, click an option on the radio button, and then click save.  My work is saved properly.
3. In an alternative flow, I try to click save while my cursor is still in the text area, and nothing happens.  Then, if I click on the save button a second time, the form saves correctly.  I've tried setting a breakpoint at the very beginning of the `save` method, and confirmed that it is not called during the first button click, and is then called correctly with the second button click.
4. I've tried to make a minimal example as a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue, but I can't isolate the buggy behavior.

**What could be preventing the click event and `save` function the first time I click the button?**  Do you have any tips or recommendations for helping debug an issue like this?

### Update: Using a Javascript Profiler

I went back and used a profiler to dig in on what's happening.  Here was my process:

1. Set up page for test, with everything filled in except the primary textarea
2. Start profiler
3. Type a letter into the textarea and wait for onchange handlers to fire, which is evidenced by Save button becoming enabled
4. Wait several seconds
5. Click Save - nothing happens
6. Stop profiler

And here's my profile:
[image]

What's interesting is that there's a **clear flurry of activity** when the onchange handlers fire, seen as a visible spike in the flame chart.  However, when I click save the first time, there is no javascript execution captured at all!  Very curious...

Comment: When you click the button, isn't the textarea suppose to lose focus?

Use a javascript profiler (in browser) to verify whether there is a call to preventDefault/stopPropagation anywhere.

Comment: @Zuhaib, Thanks for the suggestion.  I've used a profile, and don't see any calls to preventDefault or StopPropagation.  Updating the answer with what I see.